# Ways to access variable outside of program (Python)

Tags: python

I have detector based on YOLOv5, that constantly processing RTSP stream frame by frame (with fps from 10 to 100) inside of loop, so basically:

```
dataset = LoadStreams(source)
for im in dataset:
    pred = model(im)
    pred = non_max_suppression(pred)
    ...
```

I want to constantly access frames (and predictions) outside of this detection process (so parts of program with different tasks (detector, webserver, database, etc) can work in their own container so system can be more robust). How it should be done from best practice point?

I thought about using tmpfs or should I learn to use comething like Kafka for this case?

Comment: Why is this tagged multiprocessing? If you mean by that tag to communicate that you want something that uses multiprocessing.Queue, that's a very specific architecture choice and rules out some other options.

Comment: Anyhow -- a lot of this depends on your deployment environment and surrounding toolchain. If you _already_ use Kafka, then use Kafka! (Same for Redis, or NATS, or RabbitMQ, or so forth). If you scale up rather than out (replacing your harder with a faster single machine instead of adding more nodes), on the other hand, then maybe tmpfs or such makes sense. There's not one "best practice" answer, and best practice questions are generally considered opinion-based / too broad to be on-topic here regardless.

Comment: Wow, I haven't tagged it as multiprocessing, it was edited. I haven't used any message brokers and everything should work one one machine, so maybe tmpfs should be enough. Also I was looking for a different opinions (or more exactly pros and cons of different approcahes), because I haven't designed such systems before. Using RabbitMQ or Kafka is a solution with an aim to the future, but it'll cost some resources. Using tmpfs is simpler but maybe it can have bigger impact on performance. I'll try RabbitMQ (it lighter apparently) AND tmpfs to decide I wouldn't recieve an answer here. Thanks!

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't use RabbitMQ for new systems -- it's a classic, but modern replacements like NATS are much easier to admin (RabbitMQ can be a pain to fix when it breaks). Anyhow -- the main reason _not_ to use tmpfs is if you want components to be running on different systems or as isolated users; if that doesn't apply to you, it doesn't apply to you.